# Spark - Cannot Write To Parquet File when using mapWithInputSplit

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to solve a simple log parsing problem: given N log files
logfile.20160601.txt
logfile.29169692.txt
...
I would save a parquet file with the date key of the log.

In order to accomplish that I found this way in order to get the inputSplit path.

```
val data = sc.textFile("/logdirectory/*.*")
val logsWithFileName = data.mapPartitionsWithInputSplit { (inputSplit, iterator) =>
      val file = inputSplit.asInstanceOf[FileSplit]
      val logDateKey = getDatekeyFromPath(file)

      iterator.map { tpl => ( logDateKey, tpl._2.toString) }
      }
val logs = logsWithFileName.map(item => LogItem(item._1,item._2))
val df = logs.toDF
```

Now I try to save the dataframe

df.write.partitionBy("logdatekey", "hostname").save("C:/temp/results.parquet")

but I receive this message

```
Output directory file:/C:/temp/results.parquet already exists
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory file:/C:/temp/results.parquet already exists
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:132)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1179)
```

Does anyone experimented this strange behavior? Could this be related to the use of input split?

Many thanks in adavance
Rob

Comment: Have you deleted all the files that are in C:/temp/results.parquet ?

Comment: Yes, I did this in a test suite cleaning all the content before running test

Answer (score 1):

Well you error message says allo. You are trying to write an output that already exist.

You just need to what are the available save operations :

> Save operations can optionally take a SaveMode, that specifies how to handle existing data if present. It is important to realize that these save modes do not utilize any locking and are not atomic. Additionally, when performing a Overwrite, the data will be deleted before writing out the new data.

- `SaveMode.ErrorIfExists` (behavior by default) when saving a DataFrame to a data source, if data already exists, an exception is expected to be thrown.
- `SaveMode.Append` - when saving a DataFrame to a data source, if data/table already exists, contents of the DataFrame are expected to be appended to existing data.
- `SaveMode.Overwrite` - means that when saving a DataFrame to a data source, if data/table already exists, existing data is expected to be overwritten by the contents of the DataFrame.
- `SaveMode.Ignore` - means that when saving a DataFrame to a data source, if data already exists, the save operation is expected to not save the contents of the DataFrame and to not change the existing data. This is similar to a CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS in SQL.

So if your case, if you want to overwrite your existing data, you should do the following :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode

df.write.partitionBy("logdatekey", "hostname").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save("C:/temp/results.parquet")
```